# How to understand the schematic symbol of this isolated, filtered BNC connector?

Tags: emc, symbol, emi-filtering, bnc, schematic

I found some isolated panel-mount BNC connectors which have an integrated capacitor for RF chassis-bonding, e.g. [this molex part 73100-0090](https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/731000090_sd.pdf).

The datasheet contains this simple schematic to illustrate the connection of the terminals:

[image]

Obviously, the capacitor connects between the shell and the grounded parts (posts and compression clip).

**But how is the pin electrode (A) connected in this scheme?**

Image and 3-d view available [here](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0731000090/1465144):

Kind regards.

Comment: I assume that "A" is the center conductor.  If so, I would end the "A"  line with a small circle at the center of the larger circle, rather than continuing it across to the reverse arrow.  The symbol as drawn seems confusing to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From datasheet.  A is shielded conductor.

[image]

Symbol is IEC60617.  From IEC60617 .

[image]

> Coaxial plug and socket
> If the coaxial plug or socket is connected to a coaxial pair, the tangential stroke shall be extended on the appropriate side.

[image]

> Female contact (of a socket or plug) Socket.

So Molex's schematic symbol is a blending of the alternative input connection (03–A2–01) with coaxial socket (03–03–15).

A is the central contact, B is the BNC connection, C is the connector chassis and compression spring.  C is isolated from B by *an integrated capacitor* [9.4nF] *for RF chassis-bonding* (OP).

Comment: Correlate everything and this will be a great answer: A is the pin, B is the BNC ring/cylinder, C is the BNC threads and compression spring. It is not clear from the drawings, but B must be isolated from C. There is a cap from B to C.

Answer (score 1):

A (the coaxial connector Center contact) is directly connected to the "A" PCB solder pin.

"C" in the diagram above, appears to go to from the outer shell of the coaxial connector to the chassis, via a compression 'spring' flange, as shown in the datasheet (see center of the datasheet).  I think "C" in this case does not stand for 'capacitor'.

"B" is also the shell (outside) of the coaxial connector, and goes directly to the "B" PCB solder pin.

Comment: The datasheet clearly mentioned the integrated filtering cap of 9400 pF, X7R, so there *is* a capacitor. Also: How is A connected to B ? What does the arrow tip mean between A and B ?

Comment: The datasheet seems to be unnecessarily confusing, lacking call-outs, and showing what appear to be erased features for the "B" pcb pin.   An actual photo of the part would be informative.

Comment: Yes, one end of the cap is attached to the outer coaxial conductor, the other end to the compression spring (that should contact the chassis when the jack is mounted in a metal box).

Comment: added image link and 3d view to the OP

Comment: The image looks as described above.  Any more questions?

Comment: Yes, my only question as originally highlighted in bold doesnt seem answered. Specifially what is the connection between A and B ?

Comment: A (the coaxial connector Center contact) is directly connected to the "A" PCB solder pin.  Nothing else.

Comment: Could you please add some rationale behind the arrow tip between A and B ? This is the part that confuses me. If it werent for this arrow, I would have never had any doubts about A and B being fully and unconditionally isolated.

Comment: A, B, C are terminations (with A, B being PCB pins and C being a chassis contact).  The "A" solder pin goes to the "<" jack pin, that accepts a male contact from the coax connector.  It's *unfortunate* that the center of the "<" hits the shield 'circle', implying a connection from"A" to "B" (where there is none).  If there were a connection, it would be a dead-short.  It's a confusing symbol, with an unclear datasheet.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that "<" denotes a female connector. Makes sense, If you could update this info in your answer (for other people's sake) I will accept it. I found another one similar part where the < seems offset and in not in contact with the circle. I also found a much clearer schematic from a similar Amphenol part, where the center contact is indeed drawn fully separate. https://cdn.amphenol-icc.com/media/wysiwyg/files/drawing/456ex17h.pdf